# Function of "也" in "一点儿也不喜欢"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence "我一点儿也不喜欢这件衣服", translated as "I don't like this piece of clothing at all", what is the function of "也"?

Is it valid to think of this syntax as "not even a little bit [do I like this thing]"?

Some resources [1] suggest interchangeability with "都" in this context. Is that valid, or do they hold different connotations or used in different contexts?

1: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22not_at_all%22_with_%22yidianr_ye_bu%22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both “也”  and "都" in “一点儿也不喜欢” / “一点儿都不喜欢” functions as the adverb "even" (*used to emphasize something surprising or extreme*)

"一点儿**也**不喜欢" = "not liking it **even** a little"

Similar example:

"一元**也**不值" = "not worth **even** one dollar"

"(最后)一元**也**需要还清" = "have to payback in full **even** (the last) one dollar"

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in [zdic](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B9%9F)
(Section 1）
2 在否定句里表示语气的加强：一点儿～不错。

4 文言语气助词（❶表判断；❷表疑问；❸表停顿；❹形容词尾）。

(Section 2) 
1用在句末表示判断或肯定语气。相当于“啊”、“呀”

可以把‘也’交换成 ‘都’吗？这取决于上下文，在你的句可以。

我一点儿也不喜欢这件衣服。
我一点儿都不喜欢这件衣服。